# Enable OK Google detection when connected to car bluetooth

Tags: automation, voice-recognition, google-assistant

I have set "OK Google" detection to "in Google app" only. I don't want Google to be listening all the time.

However, I would like "OK Google" detection to work when I'm driving. This means that the phone's bluetooth is connected to the audio receiver in the car.

Is there a way to turn OK google detection when my phone connects to this specific bluetooth device and off again when I disconnect?

If not, is it possible to turn it on when bluetooth is turned on? (I rarely use bluetooth for anything else.)